# Send Email To Multiple (Each Line Email Address) and Print

Tags: php, html, forms, email

I am not good at PHP but still trying to create a test script so that i can learn it. I am referring to w3schools and i don't know how good or bad i am.
I need some changes to be made to what script i just created.

```
<?php

$to = $_POST['EmailList'];
$subject = $_POST['EmailSubject'];
$message = $_POST['EmailBody'];

// Always set content-type when sending HTML email
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

// More headers
$headers .= 'From: <admin@admin.com>' . "\r\n";

mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

print_r($headers)
?>

<html>
<center>
<form method="post">
<br><strong>PHP Email Sender</strong><br><br><br>

Email List<br>
<textarea name="EmailList" placeholder="email@email.com (New Email Each Line)"  rows="20" cols="50"></textarea><br><br>

Subject<br>
<input type="text" name="EmailSubject" placeholder="Your Subject Goes Here"><br><br>

Body<br>
<textarea name="EmailBody" placeholder="Write your content (HTML Accepted)"  rows="20" cols="50"></textarea><br><br>

<input type="submit" value="Submit!">
</form><br><br>

</center>
</html>
```

1. I want some help so that i can send email's to different email's but each email would be in a different line and i would not be using a comma(,). I want the script to generate the comma(,) by its own and carry each email from a new line.
2. For example i entered 10 emails i need each email to be printed and a message saying sent besides that.

Please let me know if this is possible. I just need some help.

Comment: `explode()` on line-break then `foreach()` loop to send the mail

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You may consider posting over at [codereview.se] - that might be a better fit for this type of question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is tested:

```
<?php
$subject = $_POST['EmailSubject'];
$message = $_POST['EmailBody'];

// Always set content-type when sending HTML email
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

// More headers
$headers .= 'From: <admin@admin.com>' . "\r\n";
$emailList = explode("\n",$_POST['EmailList']);
if(count($emailList) > 0){
  foreach($emailList as $to){
    $to = trim($to);
    $sent = mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    if ($sent){
      echo "<p>Sent: $to</p>";
    }
    else{
       echo "<p>Not Sent: $to</p>";
    }
  }
}
else{
  echo "<p>No email addresses</p>";
}
print_r($headers);

?>
```

Comment: There are actually many errors but with this i actually got a lot of help. I figured out the each line issue. The only issue i have now is print issue. I'll try to fix it myself. Still any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Fixed all errors, now is tested.  And I received the emails.

Comment: Awesome. It is now fixed and working like a charm. Thanks for the help friend.